# JAVASCRIPT function in constructor

Tags: javascript, function, methods, constructor

What's the differece between

```
function Set(){
    this.a =1;
    this._v2s=function(){};
    this._v2s.next = 1000;
}
```

and

```
function Set(){
    this.a =1;
    _v2s =function(){};
    _v2s.next = 1000;
}
```

and

```
function Set(){
    this.a =1;
}

Set._v2s = function(){};
Set._v2s.next =1000;
```

A little bit confused because they don't act like the same with each other

Comment: With each one what were your expectations, and what was the outcome? You might be able to answer your own question if you run through the basics.

Comment: First `_v2s` is for class instance objects, at second it is a global variable and property function in the last case.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you are essentially constructing a class with your function, where the value `this.a` and `this.v2` are being applied to your new object.

in the second example

```
_v2s =function(){};
_v2s.next = 1000;
```

Is a global variable. A `new Set` would set a global variable `_v2s` with the property `next`

In the third one, you are setting the `_v2` property onto the class itself. this means that when you construct your `Set`, `_v2` will not be created with your set. It can only be accessed via a call to `Set._v2`

Hope that wasnt confusing.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error: without `var`, it's a global variable.

Comment: True indeed. I have to modify my response.

Answer (score 0):

To explain the differences between your three examples, let's suppose you're calling your Set function with the new keyword for it to act like a constructor :

```
var mySet = new Set();
```

**1. First example :**

```
function Set(){
    this.a =1;
    this._v2s=function(){};
    this._v2s.next = 1000;
}

var mySet = new Set();
```

What this code defines :

- `Set` : object (of prototype `Function.prototype`)
- `mySet` : object (of prototype `Set.prototype`) with 2 own properties :

  - `a` : number (value = 1)
  - `_v2s` :  an object (of prototype Function) with an own property named next that is a number (value = 1000)

**2. Second example :**

```
function Set(){
    this.a =1;
    _v2s =function(){};
    _v2s.next = 1000;
}

var mySet = new Set();
```

What this code defines :

- `Set` : object (of prototype `Function.prototype`)
- `mySet` : object (of prototype `Set.prototype`) with 1 own property :

  - `a` : number (value = 1)
- _v2s : the same as before, except it's now a global variable and no longer an own property of `mySet`

**3. Third example :**

```
function Set(){
    this.a =1;
}

Set._v2s = function(){};
Set._v2s.next =1000;

var mySet = new Set();
```

What this code defines :

- `Set` : object (of prototype `Function.prototype`), with 1 own property :

  - `_v2s` : the same as before, except it's now an own property of the `Set` object.
- `mySet` : object (of prototype `Set.prototype`) with 1 own property :

  - `a` : number (value = 1)